# Is it a sin to use infinite recursion for infinite loops in Python?

Tags: python, c, recursion, infinite-loop, function-calls

This question is more about curiosity than utility. If I'm writing a function that's supposed to run for ever, for instance a daemon, how would Python handle it if I called the function again from the end of the function?

```
def daemonLoop():

    # Declare locals

    # Do stuff

    daemonLoop()
```

I'm fairly sure that doing this in **C** would result in a stack overflow, but given the level of abstraction from **C** to Python I'm guessing stuff is handled differently.

Would I go to hell for this?

Comment: People go to hell for demon loops, not for daemons ;-)  In Python, you will just get an exception, "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In almost all Python interpreters that will cause a stack overflow, as it would in C. The higher-level feature that would permit this is called [Tail Call Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) or Tail Recursion Elimination, and [the benevolent dictator of Python opposes adding this to the language](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html).

This style is considered to be non-idiomatic for Python, and a simple `while True:` loop is preferred.

Answer (score 5):

The maximum recursion depth can be retrieved with [`sys.getrecursionlimit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) and set with [`sys.setrecursionlimit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit).

> Would I go to hell for this?

Yes. CPython has no Tail Recursion Elimination / Last Call Optimization.

```
def recurse():
    recurse()

recurse()
```

Error:

```
  # 1000 or so lines of this:
  File "", line 2, in recurse
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Answer (score 1):

The C version of the Python interpreter (which is probably what you're using) will raise an error eventually if you never return from `daemonLoop`.  I'm not sure about other versions.

Comment: Why would the interpreter raise an error if you never return? This is either unclear or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you'd think about doing something like that when you could simply have an infinite `while` loop. Anyway for your question about whether it will work:

```
...
  File "test.py", line 7, in daemonLoop
    daemonLoop()
  File "test.py", line 7, in daemonLoop
    daemonLoop()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

So yeah, hell it is.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a good idea....

```
def forever(): forever()

forever()
```

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

http://paulbarry.com/articles/2009/09/02/infinite-recursion

Answer (score 0):

```
(define forever (lambda () (forever)))
```

This kind of recursion is what Lisp dialects like Scheme are made for!

Comment: Yeah, but that wasn't the question.